# Check if initial guess is feasible

Tags: drake

How do we verify that an initial guess is feasible?

There should be some API call prog.CheckInitialGuess feasible or something like that, so we don't need to add a lot of extra code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have a function [CheckSatisfiedAtInitialGuess](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a40e98056457ab5ff0855a167b2a057dc) You could call it through

```cc
prog.CheckSatisfiedAtInitialGuess(prog.GetAllConstraints());
```

to check whether all constraints are satisfied.

If you want to return the infeasible constraints, you can try

```cc
std::vector<Binding<Constraint>> failed_constraints;
for (const auto& constraint : prog.GetAllConstraints()) {
  if (!prog.CheckSatisfied(constraint, prog.initial_guess())) {
    failed_constraints.push_back(constraint);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a turnkey option to report the failed constraints? I guess we could use the original loop code you wrote

Comment: I edit my answer to add the loop for reporting the failed constraints.